# Path Bases routing with application gateway in container app is updating the ip address when hitting the ip in browser

Tags: azure, azure-application-gateway

How can I maintain the original IP  while using path-based routing in Azure Application Gateway? Currently, when I access /front, it automatically converts to the URL https://.azurecontainerapps.io/front. I would like the IP to remain unchanged, while still achieving the proxying to the container app URL.

Created a rule and enable the path bases routing in application gateway and with FQDN added the container app to the load balancer

Answer (score 0):

I  created container apps like below:

[image]

In Application gateway added backend pool, backend setting like below:

[image]

In routing rule added a path based rule like below:

[image]

Backend health:

[image]

> ***Note*** that: According to [MsDoc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/troubleshoot-app-service-redirection-app-service-url) the default domain name of App Services or container app it automatically converts to the URL only by default. If IP to be remain unchanged you should use custom domain.

When I use same default domain of container app it automatically redirects like below:

[image]

For custom domain, check these references:

[Manage traffic to App Service - Azure Application Gateway | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/configure-web-app?tabs=customdomain%2Cazure-portal#testing)

[Host name preservation - Azure Architecture Center | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/best-practices/host-name-preservation)